# Structural comparison in Standard ML

Tags: sml, ml, comparison-operators

I can't seem to find reference on why does this not work:

```
- (2000,1)<(2000,1);    
stdIn:18.1-18.18 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload]
  operator domain: 'Z * 'Z
  operand:         (int * int) * (int * int)
  in expression:
    (2000,1) < (2000,1)
```

Does Standard ML support structural comparison?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: Only for equality.

The strictly less than operator (<) in the top level environment is as the other comparison operators a bit "special". They are "special" in the way that they are (as the only ones) overloaded to work with both integers, reals, etc. Also the somewhat special thing about this overloading is that integer is used if a type can't be inferred (e.g., a polymorphic type was inferred `'a`).

For the case of integers the `Int.<` function is used, which only takes two integers as argument

```
- Int.<;
val it = fn : int * int -> bool
```

However for equality, the case is a bit different, as seen by the type of the equality operator

```
- op=;
val it = fn : ''a * ''a -> bool
```

Here the polymorphic type is seen to bee `''a`, note the double plings. This is because it can only be instantiated to an equality type (e.g., int, string, int'string, etc.). Note that real is not an equality type!

**Update**

The thing I normally do is to make a compare function for each (data)type i create. This way I have full control over what happens. The idea of the compare function is to return an [order](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/general.html#SIG%3aGENERAL.order%3aTY)

```
datatype order = LESS | EQUAL | GREATER
```

With this you can easily make a case expression and do the appropriate thing, instead of a `if .. < .. then .. else ..`

**Update1**

Below code is from Andreas Rossberg's comment. I have included it here for easy reading

```
fun comparePair compareA compareB ((a1, b1), (a2, b2)) =
    case compareA (a1, a2) of
      EQUAL => compareB (b1, b2)
    | other => other
```

And some examples of use

```
- comparePair Int.compare String.compare ((2, "foo"), (3, "bar"));
val it = LESS : order
- comparePair Int.compare String.compare ((3, "bar"), (3, "bar"));
val it = EQUAL : order
```

Comment: Thank you for the links, it is quite useful. Is it possible to write a generic lexicographic order given that each component is itself 'comparable' ? for instance, my type is type Date = int * int * int, what is the cleanest way to 'inherit' a lexicographic order ?

Comment: is ''a a mechanism hard wired for equality, or does it generalize to 'hashable' 'comparable' and other potentially user defined mechanism ?

Comment: @nicolas: no, equality is the only operator having special polymorphic support. To construct a lexicographic order for, say, pairs, you can easily write a combinator: `fun comparePair compareA compareB ((a1, b1), (a2, b2)) = case compareA (a1, a2) of EQUAL => compareB (b1, b2) | other => other` and use it like `comparePair Int.compare String.compare ((2, "foo"), (3, "bar"))`. This generalises to all sorts of other polymorphic types (e.g. triples, lists, trees), or other operations like hashing, in the obvious way.

Comment: Chapter 14 (Built-in variables and functions) of the [Moscow ML Language Overview](http://itu.dk/people/sestoft/mosml/mosmlref.pdf) gives a short description of how this overloading is done. Note it is specific for MosML, but I expect SML/NJ to do somewhat the same.

Comment: A more interesting example, showing how this composes arbitrarily: `List.collate (comparePair (comparePair Int.compare Int.compare) String.compare) ([...], [...])` -- that is, the library already provides `List.collate` as the generic lexicographic comparison function for lists.

Comment: Good to know. I think F# flavor is better designed in that respect. I guess SML does not have static generic constraints either. I wish it was possible for all those langages to have efficient type classes.